# Excel Data Mapping and Transformation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, dax

I am new to excel and I have a problem in excel that I have some values and I want to transform them into some text values. I guess It's a DAX function or something. but unable to figure out.

**for example I have this table:**

[image]

and after applying some kind of transformation it should convert gender 1 to male and 2 to female.

other than that there are age limits like 1-15,16-30 etc so age should change according to limit

**output:**

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a lookup table (?)

Comment: @BigBen I guess so I am not sure, I just need to transform input data to that output

Comment: There are examples online - use VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH.

Comment: @BigBen VLookup values basically lookup data but I want to replace like for 1 to "male" and for 22 to "16-30" in data

Comment: To replace will take vba.

Comment: @ScottCraner can we calculate fields in power pivot? if we make another table like Gender in which 1 indicates male and 2 indicate females and somehow calculate the field of the main table?

Comment: I found a good solution to create a new table with lookup values and make a relation of the main table and lookup table in power pivot and use Related function of DAX to calculate column....

Comment: @ImranAhmadShahid , please share you founded solution for this question thorough answer. So that. it will help other to get some ideas.

Comment: @Regiz I did thanks :)

Comment: You could use the find / replace in the edit menu to replace the 1's and 2's... much less work than all those relationship tables...

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution for this using power pivot option of excel:

I already have this table:

[image]

I created Gender worksheet:

[image]

and after than an age group worksheet in excel:

[image]

Then I went to a power pivot option and add all these sheets in the data model and created a relation between all tables like this:

[image]

After then I calculated columns that are required using the Related function of DAX which fetches data from another table if you have a relationship with it.

[image]

[image]

so this created my desire result.

Comment: Great! Well did